# ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry WriteToConfig needs call to ServerCertificateValidationCallback first

Tags: c#, active-directory, wif, ws-security, ws-federation

We are using ADFS and WIF as an authentication and authorization mechanism. Recently we came across a problem with our development server whereby after logging on, the screen would go blank.

We traced this to an invalid certificate on the server.

A colleague of mine, came across an article

[Auto-Update of the Signing Keys via Metadata](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/04/02/auto-update-of-the-signing-keys-via-metadata/)

That takes you through an example where the signing keys are automatically updated.

My issue is that on my colleague's machine, this works fine, but on mine I have to add the following code to the function RefreshValidationSettings mentioned in the link to include:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };
```

I have looked around, but can only find references on using this snippet above, not what is causing it.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the reason for this was the location of the certificate.

On opening up certificate manager and expanding the folders, it was discovered that the certificate used had been placed in the personal folder and not the trusted root certificates.

To resolve, just delete the certificate from the personal folder and re-install it as a trusted root certificate